# New Java syntax suggestion plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, netbeans

Does anyone know a good IDE plugin to suggest new (8 or later) Java syntax for old Java syntax?

For example,

Old syntax:

```
long count = 0;
for (String elem : list) {
    if (elem.startsWith("C")) {
        count += elem.length();
    }
}
```

Suggested new syntax:

```
long count = list.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("C")).mapToInt(s -> s.length()).sum();
```

Comment: 1.) Intellj is already a good job in that direction 2) you can't expect every possible transformation beeing suggested - that would be too complex 3) streams are not always "better" 4) asking for tools, plugins, etc is not suggested on SO

Comment: @AKSW Thanks. I also think this question is strictly off-topic in SO, but may be useful for someone.

Comment: Probably. I don't have a better answer - I'm really happy with IntelliJ and your example might already work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ does this out of the box. The following listing

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
long count = 0;
for (String elem : list) {
   if (elem.startsWith("C")) {
     count += elem.length();
   }
}
```

was successfully converted to

```
long count = list.stream().filter(elem -> elem.startsWith("C")).mapToLong(String::length).sum();
```

using the `Replace with sum` inspection.

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA if you like it please accept the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)